# Svg and text changing alignment based on screen size

Tags: html, css, svg, alignment, responsive

I have an svg element and a text inside a flexbox. I was trying to align these elements in order to keep the centered, but suddenly, when I tried on a different device, with a different screen size, both the svg and the text got out of place. Is there a way to keep them fixed?
Here's the code:

```
 <div class="f-30w f-col sub-card menu-item">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
                          <path class="circle" id="perc_circle"
                            stroke-dasharray="60, 100"
                            d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                          />
                          <path class="circle external"
                            stroke-dasharray="100, 100"
                            d="M18 2.0845
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                              a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                          />
                        </svg>
                        
                        <h4 style="position: absolute;margin: 1.9rem 2.7rem;font-size: 20px;">{{livello_pulito}}</h4>
                        <h4 style="
                        font-size: 9px;
                        position: absolute;
                        margin: 3.1rem 1.8rem;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        ">LIVELLO</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css you would have to put this:

```
    @media (max-width: 812px) {
       h4 {
          margin: 0px;
        }
    }
```

Change the 812px to your devices screen width. I don't know what device you are using it on so I can't tell you the exact px size. Then put the styles in the brackets so it looks good on your device.